# Python function that adds nested list to value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a function that adds a list of lists to a key in a dictionary based on a condition. The dataframe looks similar to the following:

```
labels        TEXT
 -1    this is a sentence...
 -1    this is a sentence...
  1    this is a sentence...
  2    this is a sentence...
  2    this is a sentence...
  3    this is a sentence...
  3    this is a sentence...
```

I want every key in the dictionary to have values associated with them based on the `df.labels` I have.

Is there a way to append the string to the values of a dictionary? This is the code I have so far.

```py
def function(df):
    
    my_nums = list(set(df.labels.tolist()))
    
    my_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(my_nums)):
        for k in range(len(df)):
            if my_nums[i] == df.labels[k]:
                # add the list of lists to a key in the dictionary
                # my_dict[label_nums[i]] = df.TEXT[k] doesn't quite work.
           
    return my_dict
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `groupby`, construct lists (this creates a Series that maps labels to lists) and use `to_dict` method to construct a dictionary:

```
out = df.groupby('labels')['TEXT'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{-1: ['this is a sentence...', 'this is a sentence...'],
 1: ['this is a sentence...'],
 2: ['this is a sentence...', 'this is a sentence...'],
 3: ['this is a sentence...', 'this is a sentence...']}
```